# How to create global variable for Dev and production api? Vue 3

Tags: vue.js

I need to create a global **variable** for production and for dev?
I tried something but variable value return `undefined`

I am created `.env` and `.env.prod` in **root** folder of project

```
VUE_APP_ROOT_API=https://api.api
```

and

```
mounted() {
  alert(process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_API) // undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/ in `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        VUE_APP_ROOT_API: JSON.stringify(process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_API),
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```